# Cognos CM-REQ-4290 error Content Manater failed to execute the script

Tags: batch-file, report, cognos

I've set up the Content Manager in Cognos 8 with the CM.OutputLocation and CM.OutputScript parameters. Cognos is correctly saving the report output and report .xml specification to this directory.

I've written a batch file that will process the Cognos report file and .xml file. It renames the report back to its original name and moves it into the correct folder. The script runs great from a Command Prompt.

I've set up the CM.OutputScript to run this script when the report is finished. However, the script doesn't run, and I get the error:

134.64.2.100:9300   3372    2016-07-08 10:41:50.436 -6                  Thread-101  CM  6013    1   Audit.cms.CM                Warning     CM-REQ-4290 Content Manager failed to execute the script "D:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\htdocs\cognos_archive.bat" when saving the report output "/content/folder[@name='Report Views']/folder[@name='Test']/reportView[@name='Test Licensed Bandwidth Weekly CSV']/reportVersion[@name='2016-07-08T15:41:49.686Z']/output[@name='2016-07-08T15:41:50.358Z']" to file.

It's not a permissions problem, as I have granted all users permission to run the script. It's not a bug in the script, as I replaced it with a two-line "Hello World" script, and I still get the same error. If I copy the script path into a Command Prompt window, it runs just fine.

Comment: Hi Bruce.  I presume that the script is present at the path in the error message on the Content Manager machine.  Is that the case?  This seems like whichever machine is trying to run the script can't find it at the specified path.  I wonder if you couldn't use a UNC network path to ensure that it is accessible from your various nodes in this Cognos environment.

Comment: This was a good suggestion, but it didn't work at first. However, I tried it with double quotes around the UNC path, and it did work. (My path has some spaces in it.) So I tried my original path with double quotes around it, and it also worked correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that my path had spaces in it, and as we know with Windows commands, a path with spaces in it has to be enclosed in double quotes when using it on the command line. I put double quotes around my path:

```
"D:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\htdocs\cognos_archive.bat"
```

and the script gets executed after the report is generated. This is confusing because the CM.OutputLocation parameter does not require the quotes if there are spaces in its path.